# error soap wsdl web service deploy c++?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, wsdl, gsoap

how to create a web service on ubuntu - c++ ? can someone please give me a tutorial with a web service deploy and also an example with a web service client . I need to have an wsdl url twhich to access from windows.

I didn;t find any good example with gsoap wsdl soapcpp2 web service deploy and client access.
I am new to this stuff and need help, appreciate thx

these are the errors i receive at client:

```
In function `currentTimeProxy::currentTimeProxy(soap const&)':
soapcurrentTimeProxy.cpp:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to `soap::soap(soap const&)'
/tmp/cc17wwP6.o: In function `currentTimeProxy::currentTimeProxy(soap const&)':
soapcurrentTimeProxy.cpp:(.text+0xa8): undefined reference to `soap::soap(soap const&)'
/tmp/cc17wwP6.o: In function `currentTimeProxy::soap_stream_fault(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)':
soapcurrentTimeProxy.cpp:(.text+0x31a): undefined reference to `soap_stream_fault'
/tmp/cc17wwP6.o:(.rodata._ZTI16currentTimeProxy[typeinfo for currentTimeProxy]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for soap'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Are you sure that you've included -lgsoap++ when you are building the gsoap server?  The server either needs to link with this library or have the source stdsoap2.cpp included in the build.

Comment: thx. i solved the error. you were right!